# Date format with array

Tags: php, datetime

I have a query to get `date_created` from the database

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `title`, `main_image`, `services`, `date_created` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $main_image, $services, $date_created);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $news[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'main_image' => $main_image, 'services' => $services, 'date_created' => $date_created];
}
```

When I want to show `date_created` in HTML with the format `d/m/Y H:i`

```
foreach ($news as $new) {
    date_format($new['date_created'], "d/m/Y H:i")
}
```

Get error `Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in`

Comment: You need to parse `$new['date_created']` into a `DateTime` object.

Comment: `date_format(date_create($new['date_created']), "d/m/Y H:i")`

Comment: Thanks, @tttony this works, you can post the answer and I will approve it. Also, thank you Barmar

Answer (score 2):

[`date_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) is an alias of [`DateTime::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and the second parameter must also be a [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object so you can use [`date_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create) that just create a `DateTime` object

```
date_format(date_create($new['date_created']), "d/m/Y H:i");
```